# Trying to rewrite code javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey I am trying to rewrite this code but it only works partially the code is suppose to move the box at the same time that it moves the content div. The content div .c_right only moves but the .icon-menu-2 does not move. How can I fix this code? Here is the code:

```
var timer;

$(".icon-menu-2").animate({marginRight: "30px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"});
$(".c_right").animate({marginRight: "215px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"}
, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
$(".icon-menu-2").animate({marginRight: "-155px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"});      
$(".c_right").animate({marginRight: "215px", display: "toggle"}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
    }, 500);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5b5zH/3/

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer;

$(".icon-menu-2").animate({marginRight: "30px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"});
$(".c_right").animate({marginRight: "215px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"}
, function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $(".c_right").animate({marginRight: "215px", display: "toggle", 'padding-right':$(".c_left").width()}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"}, 500);

$(".icon-menu-2").animate({marginRight: "-155px", queue: false, duration: "slow", display: "toggle"});   
        $(".c_left").animate({marginRight: "215px", display: "toggle"}, {queue: false, duration: "slow"})
    }, 500); 

});
```

Does this work for you? Not to sure what you want out of this

http://jsfiddle.net/7mFGx/